# Weight painting bleeding onto adjacent faces

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

How can I delete the extra weight painting from the unselected area?
I've selected an Area in the weight painting mode, and when I click to paint, there is weight paint over the other area.

It's like the part I want painted, the red, is bleeding onto the connected vertices.

Here is a screen :

[image: weight painting mode showing the issue]

Comment: This isn't a real solution, but a possible workaround that could work to add more geometry to the object so that the weights don't spill over as far. You could do this by adding loop cuts, insetting faces, or subdividing it.

Comment: @Leo No solution work, it just reduct the size of the problem ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really a "problem." OK, it is a problem for you, but it is how it is supposed to work.

When you [weight paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/introduction.html), you are adding weights to the vertices, not the faces. So anywhere you have faces sharing a vertex, you are going to have the weights "bleed" to the other face.
[image: selection and weights in weight paint mode]
In that picture the two cubes share two vertices. On the left is what I selected and applied a weight of one; on the right are the weights.

The simplest way to remedy your situation is to disconnect the two faces.
Select the vertices shared by the two different parts and press <kbd>V</kbd>, without doing anything else press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or right click to cancel the transform.

Now hover over the part that should have zero weights, and press <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked. In the *Data* tab of the properties panel assign that selection a weight of zero.

[image: weights in the same mesh]

Comment: Thank you so much, you save me a lot of time. It was exactly what I wanted !